# alphabet increment in c programming

Tags: c, increment

I'm trying to make a program that can get a char from the user and display the next letter in the alphabet. So if you entered 'a' it would print 'b' I'm new to C and I'm not quite sure how to do it. 
This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    char firstLetter [2],  secondLetter [2];
    printf ("Type in a single letter:");
    scanf ("%s", &firstLetter);
    secondLetter = (int)firstLetter++
    printf ("The letter after %s is %s",firstLetter, secondLetter );
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to have letter temporarily be an integer so that I could increase it by one but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `*secondLetter = *firstLetter + 1;`

Comment: `scanf ("%s", &firstLetter);` -> `scanf ("%s", firstLetter);`

Comment: thanks this helped a lot

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, not valid in `EBCDIC` ;)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - WIth the caveat that assuming letters are sequential in the character set is non-portable.  The only characters guaranteed to be sequential by the C standard are the numbers 0-9:  **5.2.1**:  "the
value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous."

Comment: @AndrewHenle If you are concerned about that, simply write `static_assert('z' - 'a' + 1 == 26, "Error: the symbol table was written by morons.");`.

Comment: @Lundin, `"Error: the symbol table was written by morons (aka IBM)."` :)

Comment: If you want to make abstraction of morons, use a constant string: `const char * alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`

Answer (score 7):

few problems I've noticed in your code.

- `firstLetter[2]`: why declare an array of characters if you want the input to be a 'single letter'?
- `scanf( "%s", &firstLetter )`: why read a string if you expect the input to be a char?
- you need to check your input

here is my solution for your problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char firstLetter;
    char secondLetter;

    printf( "Type in a single letter: " );
    firstLetter = getc( stdin );
    if ( isalpha(firstLetter) && tolower(firstLetter) != 'z' ) {
        secondLetter = firstLetter + 1;
        printf( "The letter after %c is %c\n", firstLetter, secondLetter );
    } else { 
        printf( "Invalid letter\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First no need to typecast to int. Second secondLetter = firstLetter + 1; . Why would you want to change firstLetter? Incase you want to optimise the solution by using only one variable then only firstLetter++ would have sufficed.

Comment: use **[isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/)**. simplify your logic

Comment: yes, that's a great addition, but I'm not sure if op wants simiplified code with less-familiar libraries

Comment: isalpha is a standard function ( which OP or any other c coder should familiarise with ). also it will greatly simplify your long condition : `firstLetter >= 'A' && firstLetter < 'z' && firstLetter != 'Z'` to `isalpha(firstLetter) && firstLetter != 'Z'`

Comment: I will have to check for 'z' and 'Z' anyway so i don't see how is that gonna make my condition shorter

Comment: ok so `isalpha(firstLetter) && tolower(firstLetter) != 'z'`. for to make super readable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91480/discussion-between-amdixon-and-itay-sela).

Answer (score 0):

Simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctypes.h>

int main() {
int ch = -1 ;

printf("\n Enter char >>> ");
scanf("%d", &ch);

if(isalpha(ch++)){
    printf("\n Next character is %c.",ch);
}else{
    printf("\n Ooops !!! : Either goes out of range or not valid character");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do the checks that Itay Sela has added.

Comment: You said you get character from user & want to print next letter...then why need a check ? I paid more attention to printing next character. If you want that then here it is.

Comment: is it alright now ? I have used very less checks, also best fitting to your question( I think).

Comment: More sanity checks is always good. Strictly speaking more checks means less possibility for error, thus better programming.

Comment: Remember more checks or unnecessary checks slows down your codes performance.

Comment: This question isn't about performance but about functionality. The checks are a necessity.